# EOFError: Ran out of input - Sockets,Pickle

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

So I am currently trying to use sockets with pickling to have easy data transfer. Although I keep getting the below error. If it helps I am trying to send information across the internet not a LAN. I am also calling the send function inside of a pygame loop.

```
## This is the main module
def main():
    run = True
    n = Network()
    p = n.getP()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        p2 = n.send(p)
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
    p.move()
    redrawWindow(window, p, p2)

main()

## This is the network module
import socket
import pickle

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = ExternalIp
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.p = self.connect()

    def getP(self):
        return self.p

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)

File "C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\ALevelProject\Pre-Project\Server_Making\network.py", line 25, in send
return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: could you share the full code, please?

Comment: @Ameya what else? Like where it uses send?

Comment: TCP is a byte stream oriented protocol. There is no guarantee that a single recv gets exactly 1 pickle buffer. I'm not sure of the best solution - you could put the pickle into a larger message that includes a length, but there should be some way to keep feeding data into a pickle parser until you get the full object... but I don't know how to.

Comment: I personally like zeromq for converting tcp into messsages. You create zeromq message based sockets and let it figure out the details.

Comment: @tdelaney how secure is it as I found out that apparently pickle isnt the most secure

Comment: @TheRandomGamer56 - zeromq would just be for sending the pickle payload. Pickle itself is potentially unsafe. Unpickling class instances includes loading the class module and instantiating that class. I am not aware of exploits that use malicious pickle objects, but since it does more than transfer data (it loads and executes modules you have installed), it is more risky. If you control the sender, its not such a bad problem.

Comment: But, things like JSON are data only (more precisely, fundamental python types like int and string). Its much harder to exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Pickling uses additional bytes to the actual payload to handle various encoding and marshaling purposes, so 2048 bytes data, when pickled, will be more.

You're trying to decode that fixed block size, and it's complaining that there should be more data than it has.

I'm not sure if the overhead is fixed, for a given quantity and format of data. If so you could factor that into your sizes, if not you might need to do some reading multiple smaller chunks and attempt parsing until it succeeds.

the `io` module's [BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#buffered-streams) might be useful for the latter approach.

Another option would be to define a simple length-prefixed format, where each "message" you send the size of the following pickle chunk, followed by the pickled data.

The reader can then do a `chunk_len = some_decoder_func(buf.read(4)); pickle.loads(buf.read(chunk_len))` or thereabouts.

As a side note, using pickle as a way of transferring data between game instances might not be a great idea, see the warnings in e.g. the [`pickle` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and elsewhere online about the ways it can be exploited to do unwanted things to other recipients that blindly trust it.

Comment: Its a bigger problem than that. TCP makes no guarantee that you'll receive exactly 1 pickle buffer in a recv. its not just that OP needs to ask for more data. There needs to be a way to delimit the pickle buffer.

Comment: that's a good point I overlooked. I'm not sure it's *essential* to delimit the chunks (what does pickle do if there's data left in the string/buf it's passed?) but it's almost certainly a good idea to do so.

Comment: @Shabble is there any other modules you know of that would be good for the job?